# Questions regarding a proof of Nakayama's lemma.

Tags: commutative-algebra

I refer to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama_lemma#Proof) proof of Nakayama's lemma.

1. What is $\varphi^n$? Is it $\underbrace{\varphi\circ\varphi\circ\dots\circ\varphi}_{\text{$n$ times}}$?
2. What is $\varphi\delta_{ij}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you are right. The multiplication in the endomorphism ring is composition.
2. Well, $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta, it is $0$ if $i \neq j$ and $1$ if $i \neq j$. In your situation it means that $\varphi \delta_{ij}$ is $\varphi$ if $i = j$ and the zero endomorphism if $i \neq j$.